# Understanding Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

*Definition* Let $V$ be vector space over $K$. Let $U\subseteq V$ be a subset. Suppose that

- for all $u_{1},u_{2}\in U$, $u_{1}+u_{2}\in U$
- for all $u\in U$ and $\alpha\in K$, $\alpha u\in U$
- $U$ is not empty.

**My quiston is: I think, $1$ and $0$ should be in $U$ but there is not in the definition. Should there these in the definition?**

Comment: Let alpha be 0 in the second item, no?

Comment: @The Chaz 2.0 for $\alpha=0$, this would work. I don't know what OP means with $1 \in U$, since $1$ is not a vector.

Comment: @SimonMarynissen $1$ is multiplicative inverse, isn't it? Then, why $1$ is not a vector?

Comment: $1$ is an element of $K$ not of $V$